# Configure RestAssured to use GSON over Jackson?

Tags: java, rest, gson, rest-assured

I have both GSON and Jackson in a project using RestAssured and I want to use GSON. The official documentation does not provide a clear example. I tried several configs, but it does not seem to work. Here's my config, am I missing something?

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config()
                .decoderConfig(new DecoderConfig("UTF-8"))
                .encoderConfig(new EncoderConfig("UTF-8", "UTF-8"))
                .objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig(GSON));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my project I solved it by wrapping original `RestAssured.given` method

```
public static RequestSpecification given() {
    return RestAssured.given()
        .config(RestAssured.config()
            .objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig(ObjectMapperType.GSON)));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Kotlin:

`RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(objectMapperConfig().defaultObjectMapperType(ObjectMapperType.GSON))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the [Rest Assured documentation states](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#content-type-based-serialization), the order of technologies is:

1. JSON using Jackson 2 (Faster Jackson (databind))
2. JSON using Jackson (databind)
3. JSON using Gson
4. XML using JAXB

Furthermore the use of an [explicit serializer](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#using-an-explicit-serializer) or [deserializer](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#using-an-explicit-deserializer) is also described.

Serialization:

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("My messagee");
given().
   body(message, ObjectMapperType.GSON).
when().
  post("/message");
```

Deserialization:

```
Message message = get("/message").as(Message.class, ObjectMapperType.GSON);
```

Comment: I know what the official documentation states about the order of libraries, that's why I am wondering how do I configure RestAssured to use GSON by default. Serialization/deserialization is clear, that's exactly what I am doing, but my question is about the global configuration of RestAssured. Doing explicit serialization with GSON for each call is not really feasible.